# Using a different T/X on my quadcopter

Tags: quadcopter

I have a Bugs 3 quadcopter, can I use a better transmitter from a helicopter for instance, a 2.4 GHz?

Comment: Please edit and expand your question. How are you controlling it now and hat transmitter are you currently using? Is that not a 2.4 GHz transmitter already? What have you tried already, and what did not work? What receiver does the quadcopter have? Is it 2.4 GHz compatible?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* PatrickGallagher, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I'm going to put your question *on hold* to give you an opportunity to *edit your question* to clarify what you're asking about. Specifically, you ask about using a 2.4GHz transmitter, but it looks like [it already uses a 2.4GHz transmitter](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B06XTNS8HF/).